# What is the correct syntax to return a function in Rust?

Tags: function, rust, return

What is the correct syntax to return a function in Rust?

The following code does not compile.

```
  fn identity<T>(a: T) -> T {
    return a;
  };

  fn right<T>(a: T) -> Fn {
    return identity;
  };
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f836e265d566541d2d8954383bb94eef)) is a minimal example:

```
fn identity<T>(a: T) -> T {
    return a;
}

fn right<T>(_a: T) -> impl Fn(T) -> T {
    return identity;
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", right(0)(42))
}
```

You need to:

- Specify the input argument and output types within the signature, i.e. `Fn(T) -> T`.
- Specify that `right`'s return type `impl`ements the *trait* `Fn(T) -> T`.

---

Alternatively, you could also have written the function pointer `fn(T) -> T` as the return type. Since this is not a trait, you would not need the `impl` keyword:

```
fn right<T>(_a: T) -> fn(T) -> T {
    return identity;
}
```

Only `fn` items and non-capturing closures can be coerced to function pointers, so, while simpler, this will not work in all cases.

Comment: Thanks, in fact, the correct code should be in my own answer. The return type of `right` does not have to be identical to input of `T` of `identity`.

Comment: Is it idiomatic to use `return identity;` instead of simply, `identity`?

Comment: @STF_ZBR I think most people enjoy the fact that code blocks are expressions and omit the `return`.

Answer (score 1):

#### This is the best I came up with:

```rust
fn identity<T>(a: T) -> T {
    return a;
}

fn right<T>() -> &'static dyn Fn(T)->T {
    return &identity::<T>;
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", right()(3.1415));
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=fn%20identity%3CT%3E(a%3A%20T)%20-%3E%20T%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20a%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20right%3CT%3E()%20-%3E%20%26%27static%20dyn%20Fn(T)-%3ET%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%26identity%3A%3A%3CT%3E%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20right()(3.1415))%3B%0A%7D) <-- test it by yourself.

#### Explanation

`&'static dyn Fn(T)->T` means that it returns a reference to some object that satisfy the `Fn(T)->T` trait (because yes `Fn(T)->T` is indeed a trait, not a type).

Comment: Thanks, but as @Mateen Ulhaq answered, it can be simply `fn(U) -> U` and I thought it's simpler, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is! As a beginner myself I didn't know it was possible.

Answer (score 1):

Self answer after two answers from others:

I came up with this:

```
  fn identity<T>(a: T) -> T {
    a
  };

  fn right<T, U>(_a: T) -> fn(U) -> U {
    identity
  };
```

The return type of `right` does not have to be identical to input of `T` of `identity`.